# Android: Is it possible to accelerate appearance of dropdown choice list of AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I use AutoCompleteTextView to provide an address entry. The street names are defined and provided as ArrayAdapter to provide street choices. This works. Unfortunately the dropdown appears very late because it contains more than 6000 street names. I already try to modify the threshold from 2 to 6 or so, but it's not that faster.

I guess I have to override the algorithm or something if it is possible, or maybe there is another approach to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a custom [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) that implements [`Filterable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html).  By creating your own [`Filter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html), you can design one that works faster than the default one does.

Comment: Good tip. I will try that out.